# LinkedIn Share feature

Tags: share, linkedin-api

Post LinkedIn changes (around May 2015) have disabled our use of the share feature, via API call using the URL http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json. We are now receiving a "403 authorization failed".

Steps taken to rehabilitate our share function:

1. Confirmed that ClientId & Client Secret keys are still the same as being used in our app
2. The Default Application Permissions have been confirmed, w_share is selected...which used to be rw_share (no longer available). Other selections made are r_basicprofile, r_emailaddress, & rw_company_admin...which are seemingly not related.
3. Authorized Redirect URLs are still applied for the domain we are using our application under.
4. Content type has been set to "application/xml", as suggested by other postings.

We have tried for months...hoping that any post changes to LinkedIn would have resolved our problem, yet nothing we have researched has helped. We figure that this might be a glitch from the permission modification update done by LinkedIn...since our code has never change, yet has worked for 2+ years prior to the May 2015 changes.

We would appreciate any insight as to what is going on here....as we are continuing to have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, it was because the security of Linkedin changed. We had to had to alter the statement:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

to this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are relying on the "default application permissions", you may also want to double check that your OAuth code is not still requesting the old (no longer available) member permissions (e.g. `rw_nus`) via the `?scope=` URL parameter, which will trump the "default application permissions" settings you've defined in your LinkedIn app's config.

Otherwise, the `w_share` permission should still be providing you the ability to post a share to LinkedIn.

Comment: That was a good suggestion;however, I went back and tried to find any occurrences of the old permission...and there were none. Is there anything else you can think of?